# How to define methods on prototype, rather than as class properties, without typescript errors

Tags: typescript

I want to define methods on a class prototype rather than using method properties. Why is this a typescript error?

```
interface IFoo { foo(): void }
class Foo implements IFoo {
  static {
    // property foo does not exist on type Foo
    this.prototype.foo = function () { }
  }
}
// property foo does not exist on type Foo
new Foo().foo()
```

This example [works at runtime](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG9kzYAUAlAFzIBumwAJsgL4BQCANnAM4fJY7AC2AB1YR+EcNwzY8TZMgSYQHMFACuCMJihFBUYJTiRkUCHFqLWAT2T8OAcwrK9IOyTzNZyZYeAIZcuTAAC2AOADpdTE0wS0EIMMIcAF4CVRANYEVkUjx5RQ5METDWTDsiYNCw21dGT2YPEAgAdx5iACJgMG4xNpIE4hIgA).

In my usecase I have a large complicated interface and a configuration object I could map to implementations

```
static {
  for (const name of Object.keys(config)) {
    this.prototype[name] = function () {}
  }
}
```

Comment: `foo` isn't defined on your class, that's what the compiler is complaining...

Comment: What's the difference between `static { this.prototype.foo = function () {}` and `foo() {}`?

If you check the typescript playground link, new Foo().foo() is defined and works as expected.

Comment: Would something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRBKEw) work for you?

Comment: @vr. That looks like it would, if the only difference that you've added type defs in the class? Why is that different than implementing the interface?

Comment: @everett1992 You have to add it to the class if you implement an interface. Interfaces are merely a contract that you cannot break.

Answer (score 0):

When you write :

```
  static {
    this.prototype.foo = function () { }
  }
```

You are actually writing a runtime code in the static initialization block.

You're not adding a key to the definition of the class.